# Heroku to AWS EC2 - the content must be served over HTTPS

Tags: http, heroku, amazon-ec2, https

Node app deployed on Heroku, and Asp.Net deployed on AWS EC2.

The problem now is Heroku using HTTPS but EC2 only accept HTTP.

I have tried to create SSL certificate(for Load Balancer purpose) for my Heroku app URL, verify through email. However, I didn't received any email in my personal or Heroku notification(am I missing something here?).

There are some internet sources saying that routing all HTTP port to HTTPS port in AWS security group. I did added inbound rules for HTTPS 443 to it but it is still failed.

Comment: Are you using a loadbalancer in your architecture?

Comment: I am trying to add load balancer to route the http and https, but I cannot create the SSL successfully for Heroku app...

Comment: Are you using aws certificate manager to create the certificate? If yes, then do you have access to the DNS records for the domain you are trying to create certificate for. Or do you have access to any default mailboxes such as webmaster@yourdomain.com/administrator@yourdomain.com/etc...

Comment: ya, I am using aws certificate manager to create that SSL and I don't think I have access to Heroku domain as my URL is https://xxx.herokuapps.com

Comment: Then you won't be able to create a AWS certificate in certificate manager since you don't own the domain.

Comment: then how could I resolve that error "the content must be served over HTTPS" since heroku app is running on HTTPS, and EC2 is running on HTTP?